# udp select timeout issues. Either timing out or reading from all clients

Tags: c++, c, select, udp, timeout

I am using select to handle connections on a udp server. If I do not get a packet for some period, I would like to time out. The probelm is, it seems I can either timeout correctly and only read from one client, or read from all clients and not time out.

The difference in this functionality has to do with the first argument to select, the `int nfds`

Here is my code:

```
int TIMEOUT = 5;
for (;;) {
    FD_ZERO(&read_handles); 
    FD_SET(udpFD, &read_handles); 

    timeout.tv_sec = TIMEOUT;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    if (select(udpFD+1, &read_handles, NULL, NULL, &timeout) == 0) {
        printf("Select has timed out...\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        int length = 1;
        if (FD_ISSET(udpFD, &read_handles)) {
           //process read.
        }
    }
}
```

This version does not time out. If I change the select line to:

```
if(select(udpFD, &read_handles, NULL, NULL, &timeout) == 0)
```

It does timeout, but it only receives data from one of my clients.

udpFD is the only handle I am looking at, but it has a value of 4 because it is not the first descriptor I have made. I do not know if that makes a difference because it is the max value.

How can I both timeout and get data from both of my clients?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not time out" exactly? Do you mean that it stays in `select` forever?

Comment: `select` also returns `(-1)` in the event of an error, which you are not testing for. It stands to reason that FD_ISSET will return `(0)` if this is the case. 5 seconds is a long time - it wouldn't surprise me if an `EINTR/EAGAIN` was the culprit.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes it stays in `select` forever.

Comment: @BrettHale I am only sending two messages to it right now. It also has the same behavior with a shorter timeout. I do not know if that changes the problem, but I will check error code and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c Did you 100% confirm that by logging something right before `select` and right after?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Upon doing this, I see my before only once and the after only after timeout. When trying the other case, I see the before and the after, but only once, when it shows that I have read two messages off. It is very strange.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c So then you're not getting stuck in `select`? If so, can you update your question with the new information?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You were correct, it was not getting stuck in select. I  have found my error. I was using a length field after I read my value, and was not resetting it, so I was getting stuck in a recv loop. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `if(select(udpFD+1, &read_handles, NULL, NULL, &timeout) == 0)` is the correct way to go.

This will work.

My error was later in the code I was not resetting a length field I read, and was getting stuck in the `recvfrom` loop, and only calling select once.

Comment: First argument should be udpFD+1 (not udpFD).

Comment: Any reason why? udpFD alone seems to work as expected.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c Because that's the way the method is defined. That parameter is the number of possible FDs in the set, which by definition is the highest FD plus one. If you're on Windows it's ignored, but you should get it right anyway.